# Can deploy the app from Netbeans but not from the Glassfish AdminConsole

Tags: java, glassfish, classpath, java-ee-6, packaging

I have an Enterprise project with an EJB module and a Web module.
I am trying to deploy these modules separately on Glassfish server (local) on my machine.
If I right click and deploy these projects from Netbeans, they get deployed and run good.
But if I try to deploy them from the Glassfish AminConsole,

- the ejb module gets deployed successfully without any problem.
- but the web module deployment fails.
- The ClassDefinitionNotFoundException is thrown for all the EJBs in the ejb module.
- But the ejb module jar is in the war file (in the WEB-INF/lib folder).

I am using Netbeans7.0 and Glassfish 3.1.

What's the right way to handle this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the Netbeans that did not include the ejb-jar inside my war when build the application as ear. And the fix was to build them (jar and war) individually.